# Add Nicks pallete

Tags: polkadot-js, substrate-node-template, polkadot-local

```
lenovo@lenovo-IdeaPad-3-15ADA05-Ua:~/substrate-node-template$ cargo check -p node-template-runtime
    error: failed to load manifest for workspace member `/home/lenovo/substrate-node-template/node`

Caused by:
  failed to load manifest for dependency `node-template-runtime`

Caused by:
  failed to parse manifest at `/home/lenovo/substrate-node-template/runtime/Cargo.toml`

Caused by:
  feature `runtime-benchmarks` includes `frame-benchmarking/runtime-benchmarks`, but `frame-benchmarking` is not a dependency
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to import `frame-benchmarking` in your Cargo.toml

```
frame-benchmarking = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", optional = true , branch = "polkadot-v0.9.40" }
```

Make sure `branch = "polkadot-v0.9.40"` has the same version as the rest of the imports.

Look at the substrate-node-template as an example:  https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/main/runtime/Cargo.toml#L47